# Using the present tense or past tense for a fact

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I know that we should use the present tense when talking about facts. However, in some instances I cannot decide which tense to use.

For example,

"The analysis assumes that a and b are independent of y."
"The analysis assumed that a and b are (were?) independent of y."

It is a fact that the analysis makes that assumption, yet the analysis was done in an earlier chapter.

Another example:
"He built the house in 1800." Passive: The house was built in 1800.
"He builds the house in 1800." Passive: The house is built in 1800.

Even right now in 2020, the fact remains that the house was built in 1800, so which tense is correct?

Can anyone help?

Comment: As usual, when a question here starts with "I know that ...", what is said to be known is wrong. This is almost always the cause of the question. The present tense is not used in talking about facts, but about states and repeated events. Using the present tense does not guarantee facts; you can lie in any tense. If you are talking generally, use the present. If you are talking about a particular event in the past (not something that it caused, but that past event) then use the past.

Comment: @JohnLawler Lovely trenchancy. Now I may breakfast happily!

Comment: @Anton Happy for you.